# Can I create a Java constructor like a C# constructor?

Tags: java, c#, .net, constructor

Is it possible to create a Java constructor like a C# constructor or similar. I have tried searching but couldn't find anything. Don't know if it is because I am describing it wrong or not.

In C# I can create a constructor like so

```
public class FooA
{
    public FooB _fooB { get; private set };

    public FooA(FooB fooB = null)
    {
        _fooB = fooB ?? new FooB();
    }
}
```

and it can be called like so

```
public static Main()
{
    var fooB = new FooB();
    var noArg = new FooA();
    var withArg = new FooA(fooB: fooB);
}
```

It seems like I can't have an equals null in the parameters. Just curious and laziness on my part as I would prefer to not create constructors with a combination of 20 possible parameters for my repository class.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible in java. I would recommend using the builder pattern to have more flexibility and avoid passing all the values (and their different combinations) in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks..Will check it out

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support optional parameters.

If you want something like that I can only suggest chained, overloaded methods.

EDIT: Another option is to have a single object that contains all of the input parameters. Then you can set whichever ones you want in the "holding" object and pass that into the constructor and use it as you will.